# i get Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0) error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wrote this code in controller:

```
 public ActionResult AddNotice(NoticeViewModel nVN)
    {
        BOL.User CurrentUser = userbs.user.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
        int UserId = CurrentUser.ID;

        var objNotice = new BOL.Notice()
        {
            NoticeID = nVN.SelectedNoticeTypeId,
            ProductID = nVN.ProductID,
            UserID = UserId
        };
        objBs.notice.AddNotice(objNotice);
```

methods:

```
public void AddNotice(Notice _notice)
    {
        int count = GetAllNotices().Where(x => x.UserID == _notice.UserID).Where(x => x.ProductID == _notice.ProductID).Count();
        if (count == 0)
            notice.InsertNotic(_notice);
        else
            notice.UpdateNotic(_notice);
    }
    public List<Notice> GetAllNotices()
    {
        return notice.GetAllNotices();
    }
```

and  :

```
public void UpdateNotic(Notice _notic)
        {
            db.Entry(_notic).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
        }
```

when run update i get error in `db.SaveChanges();`

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement
>   affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been
>   modified or deleted since entities were loaded

and i don't know what is problem??

Comment: Your method to add and to update using entity framework is... unusual... don't you have your `DataModel`/`ApplicationDbContext` class? Your statement should be something like `db.Notices.Add(entity)` or `db.Notices.AddOrUpdate(entity)` to add or to update

Answer (score 0):

In your `AddNotice` in the update case the `Notice` instance wasn't obtained from the same context that you are using to update it.

Change tracking depends on the entity being associated with the context and then updated.

Or you can use `IDbSet<T>.Attach(entity)` to associate an instance created elsewhere.